# angular unit testing async vs sync problems

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am very new to unit testing in angular and jasmine so I have been struggling to get it right. I am trying to write a simple unit test for a login page. The following is my code

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import {BrowserModule, By} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {Component, DebugElement, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {LoaderService} from '@shared/services/loader.service';
import {AuthenticationService} from '@shared/services/authentication.service';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {CommonService} from '@shared/services/common.service';
import {ExploreService} from '@shared/services/explore.service';
import {TitleService} from '@shared/services/title.service';
import {AppConfig} from '../../app-config.service';
import {ThemeService} from '@shared/services/theme.service';
import {MatDialog, MatFormFieldModule, MatIconModule} from '@angular/material';
import {throwError} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'show-errors',
  template: '<p>Mock Product Settings Component</p>'
})
class MockShowErrorsComponent {
  @Input() public control;
}
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  let authService: any;
  let common: any;
  let explore: any;
  let title: any;
  let config: any;
  let theme: any;
  let dialog: any;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;
  let element: HTMLElement;
  let submitSpy: any;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    authService = jasmine.createSpyObj('AuthenticationService', [
      'login',
      'logout'
    ]);
    common = jasmine.createSpyObj('commonService', [
      'updateCurrentUrl',
      'isMobile',
    ]);
    explore = jasmine.createSpyObj('exploreService', [
      'slowCalcMessage',
      'cancelSlowMessage',
      'getInventoryTotalSummary',
      'handleError',
      'getMarketData'
    ]);
    title = jasmine.createSpyObj('titleService', [
      'getTitle',
      'setTitle',
      'updateTitle',
      'updateSiteName'
    ]);
    config = jasmine.createSpyObj('AppConfigService', [
      'load',
      'API_ENDPOINT'
    ]);
    theme = jasmine.createSpyObj('ThemeService', [
      'getThemeSettings',
      'generateColorTheme',
    ]);
    dialog = jasmine.createSpyObj('dialog', [
      'open'
      ]);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
        HttpClientModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        LoginComponent,
      MockShowErrorsComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        LoaderService,
        {provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: authService},
        {provide: CommonService, useValue: common},
        {provide: ExploreService, useValue: explore},
        {provide: TitleService, useValue: title},
        {provide: AppConfig, useValue: config},
        {provide: ThemeService, useValue: theme},
        {provide: MatDialog, useValue: dialog},
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    element = debugElement.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
  it('should fail on wrong credentials', () => {
    const email = element.querySelector('#defaultForm-email') as HTMLInputElement;
    email.value = 'vigneshm@intermx.com';
    email.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    const password = element.querySelector('#defaultForm-pass') as HTMLInputElement;
    password.value = 'agira123';
    password.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const service = debugElement.injector.get(AuthenticationService);
    submitSpy = spyOn(service, 'logout');
    debugElement.query(By.css('button.login-btn'))
      .triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(submitSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

The above code is my specs and mocks for the login screen, I realized that the login page has too many dependencies which need to be simplified when starting to mock them.

The real problem is whenever I run this, the second test fails with `TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`.

I am not sure why the DOM is not available at the time of testing, I should wait for DOM or angular to be ready? or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error, the problem was with the template. I had a global *ngIf statement checking for the existence of a variable called theme settings

`<div *ngIf="themeSettings"></div>`

and in the tests, I forgot to stub the themeSettings variable, which resulted in the DOM required for the test never to be created. Once I added the stub value for the themeSettings it started to work again.

Takeaway: If you have a ngIf in your template make sure to stub it and set proper values for those values in your tests and make sure your DOM is created properly before tetsting.

Answer (score 1):

use vsc and install simon test plugin. Now right click on component for which you wan to write unit tests . select option generate tests . it will generate a spec file with all dependencies written over there. now u copy paste the test cases of ur above file.

Comment: Hi Supreeth, Thanks for the advice, I have no trouble in spying, stubbing the dependencies. I really can't understand why the email box is undefined at the time of the test is running. Is that something you can help me with?

Comment: Sure I will help

Comment: are u sending the data[email and pwd] as form data

Comment: if yes, writing tests would be much easier for you

Comment: just set wrong value for form data and send it service and in expect check for wrong response....

Answer (score 1):

Think your issue is `const email = element.querySelector('#defaultForm-email') as HTMLInputElement;` and all such `element.querySelector`

Usually you should be using `fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(className);` or `id`. As your `TestBed` is usually creating you a safe environment for running tests.

You should usually use something along the lines,

```
const password: HTMLInputElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#defaultForm-pass');
 password.setValue('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

I mocked up your test in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53445205?file=app/login.component.spec.ts).  As you can see in the Stackblitz, the tests are now both passing.  Here is what I did to get it to work:

- First of all I had to guess about your component since you didn't
  include those details.  Feel free to fork what I have done and
  replace it with your real component details to see if you can
  reproduce your error.
- I had to import both MatInputModule and BrowserAnimationsModule for
  the TestBed to create properly.
- I commented out the line `submitSpy = spyOn(service, 'logout')`,
  since you have already passed in a spy there is no need to spyOn
  again.  Therefore I also changed the last line to be
  `expect(service.login).toHaveBeenCalled();` to test the spy that was
  already passed in.
- I added an async() around the second beforeEach where you actually
  create the TestBed component.
- I added a `fixture.whenStable()` to ensure everything was rendered
  properly before testing.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @dmcgrandle, the problem was actually in my template. I had a global *ngIf for a variable called themeSettings and in the tests, I never set the value so the login template was not created. Once I fixed that, the tests started working